# Python SKlearn fit() monitor TypeError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, monitoring, data-fitting

I want to monitor my gradient boost classifier fit function

```
monitor = make_monitor(10) # a callback funtion
gs.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, monitor=monitor)
```

which gives

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'monitor'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is `gs`? A `gridSearchCV` object? or anything else? Is it a `GradientBoostingClassifier` object? If yes, then it does not support any `monitor` param.

Comment: Yes, gs is a GridSearchCV object. gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=create_pipeline(),
                  param_grid={"clf__learning_rate": np.linspace(0.01, 1.0, 10)},
                  scoring="f1",
                  cv=cv_folds,
                  n_jobs=n_jobs,
                  pre_dispatch=n_jobs+1,
                  refit=False)   I ran the fit a whole weekend without result, but it should take max. 1 hour.

Comment: Show the code for `estimator=create_pipeline()`

Comment: Yes, the problem is somehow with the pipeline. But that would lead too far here. I am now trying without a pipeline.

Comment: Maybe, but without that we cant solve your problem. Anyways, which version of sklearn are you using

Comment: The solution lies elsewhere: I am using Spyder and I had njobs=2, but only njobs=1 is working. The curious thing is that njobs=2 works just fine if I run the same code on a Jupyter notebook. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score -2):

Going from njobs=2 to njobs=1 solved the problem.